# How to install Python 3.6 to Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, python, python3

My system runs on Ubuntu 20.04 and has Python 3.8 by default. Somehow I updated to Python 3.7 (I don't remember how, only with the help of Google).

Now, I want to revert back to Python 3.6 and also want to create an environment using Python 3.6, because my project involves some packages that are available in Python 3.6

Can anyone please tell me how to make it?

When I tried to install and check the version after installation, it displayed Python 3.7 only, not 3.6, screenshot attached:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the output of `python3.6 -V`?

Comment: I would recommend installing alternate versions in a container or VM, to minimize impact on your main system.

Comment: Python 3.6 ist EOL since late 2021, so not recommended to use it anymore for new projects. If your existing project relies on Python packages only available for Python 3.6, you may want to start looking for alternatives to be future-proof.

Answer (score -1):

In order to install Python 3.6 on your Ubuntu 20.04 system, you first need to update and upgrade your system to pull the latest available version of Python 3. In your terminal, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
```

Your system will download the latest versions of packages and ask you if you want to upgrade your current packages.

You can now, check for the installed version of Python 3 using the following command from your terminal:

```
python3 -V 
Python 3.6.5
```

Comment: `python3` should always point to the default python3 version, which currently is 3.8.5 in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Learn to use python environments.